# Set UIPicker in motion like a slot machine after a button pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm very new to objective-c and IOS development. I want to create a very simple slot-machine app. For that I used an UIPicker and filled it with the required data. However I'm having trouble to make it roll after the user clicks a button. I don't have any idea how to implement that kind of movement.
Can anyone give me a direction? I don't have any code to add because everything is displayed like it should, except that method to make the picker actually move which I don't know how to implement at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by loop in animating to a specific row  , so create a timer that fires every 1 second inside it increment row / component put this

```
 [picker selectRow:row inComponent:component animated:YES];
```